# How can I find and replace all punctuation with space in node js in large text file using streaming?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, nlp

I want to find all the punctuation in any size of text file and replace it with spaces using node js. Since the file can be a large text file so I am using read & write stream onto the file to break it into the chunks and then put it into the function which will find and replace the punctuation on that text file. Please help me to find a way to get this task completed.

Comment: by punctuation you mean periods,colons, semi-colons, etc? I would just run the string through a regex, if that is what you are trying to do

Comment: How about you show the code you have so suggestions can be made on how to edit it.  @Hunter is right, this is pretty easy to do with regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [stream processing](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/advanced/streams/what-are-streams/) of Node.js and regex to accomplish this. Here is a possible solution for this:

```
var fs = require( 'fs' );

console.log( process.argv[ 2 ], '->', process.argv[ 3 ] );

var readStream = fs.createReadStream( process.argv[ 2 ] );
var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream( process.argv[ 3 ] );

readStream.on('data', function (chunk) {
  const str =  chunk.toString( 'utf-8' )
                    .replace( /[\,\.\!\;\?\/\:]/g, ' ' );
  writeStream.write( Buffer.from( str, 'utf-8' ) );
} );

readStream.on( 'end', function () {
  writeStream.end();
} );

// Some basic error handling
readStream.on( 'error', function ( err ) {
  console.log( 'ERROR', err );
} );

writeStream.on( 'error', function ( err ) {
  console.log( 'ERROR', err );
} );
```

You could add/subtract punctuations in the regex used in .replace() as per your need.